# Angular, Typescript TypeError: instanceOfClass.Method is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object, typeerror

Hello I hope you are well, I have a problem with Typescript on Angular.

Let me put it in context,

I have a component `post-preview-component.ts` from this component, I transmit the click on a button (the publish button more precisely) to the parent component with an EventEmitter:

here is the template code within `post-preview.component.html`:

```
/* code omitted for readability and simplicity */

<button mat-menu-item (click)="onPublishPressed()">
   <mat-icon style="color: blue;">publish</mat-icon>
   <span>Publish</span>
</button>

/* code omitted for readability and simplicity */
```

Here is the component code within `post-preview.component.ts`:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-preview',
  templateUrl: './post-preview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-preview.component.scss']
})
export class PostPreviewComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() post!: Post
  
  @Output() onPublishButtonPressed = new EventEmitter<void>()

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  
  constructor() {
  }

  // code omitted for readability and simplicity

  onPublishPressed(): void {
    this.onPublishButtonPressed.emit()
  }

  // code omitted for readability and simplicity

}
```

That's it for the child component **post-preview.component**.

and in the parent component, I react to this event
the template code of the parent `post.component.html`.

```
<app-post-preview *ngFor="let post of posts" [post]="post" class="mt-5"            

(onPublishButtonPressed)="publishPost(post)">

</app-post-preview>
```

voici le code component du parent `posts.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-posts',
  templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts.component.scss']
})
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {

  posts!: Post[] | undefined

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._getPosts().then(() => console.log('post loaded'))
  }

  // fetch all posts
  private async _getPosts(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      this.posts = await this._postsService.getPosts() // don't worry, all posts are fetched and the list isn't empty... posts are displayed

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    } 
  }


// button which is called to react to the click on the publish button from the child component
  publishPost(post: Post): void {

    console.log(typeof post) // print object

    console.log(post instanceof Post) // return false, but the IDE (webstorm) warning says "Redundant 'instanceof' check: 'post' has type 'Post' or an inheritor of 'Post'"

    console.log(post as Post) // I tried to cast to Post

    console.log(post instanceof Post) // always return false, and the IDE (webstorm) warning still says "Redundant 'instanceof' check: 'post' has type 'Post' or an inheritor of 'Post'"

   post.publish(publishedPost.publisher_id!, publishedPost.published_date!) // ERROR, TypeError: post.publish is not a function
  }
```

As you can see on the comments I put on the logs, the `post` received by the `publishPost` method is indeed of type `Post`, the IDE detects it too but at runtime, it's as if it became of type `Object` and lost the `Post` type.

What is wrong here and how to solve this problem ? Thanks you!

According to my research, this is a common problem with Typescript... How to solve it?

P.S.: here is my `Post` model class

```
import {PostStatus} from "../enums/post-status.enum";

export class Post {
  private readonly _id: string
  private readonly _created_date: string

  private readonly _creator_id: string

  private _status: PostStatus

  private _publisher_id?: string
  private _published_date?: string

  constructor(
    id: string,
    created_date: string,
    creator_id: string,
    status?: PostStatus,
    publisher_id?: string,
    published_date?: string,
    public editors?: string[],
    public title?: string,
    public content?: string,
    public cover_image?: string,
  ) {
    this._id = id
    this._created_date = created_date
    this._creator_id = creator_id
    this._status = status ?? PostStatus.draft
    this._publisher_id = publisher_id
    this._published_date = published_date

  }

// THERE is the publish method 
  publish(publisher_id: string, published_date: string): void {
    if (this._status == PostStatus.published) {
      throw  Error("Impossible to publish a post that has already been published")
    }

    this._publisher_id = publisher_id
    this._published_date = published_date
    this._status = PostStatus.published
  }

 }
```

Comment: Can you provide _postsService?